# React: Accessing a page outside React app, inside public folder

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application created by `create-react-app`. The app works fine, but I have run into a problem

I need to test som ad things on a plain html site, no additional React code. The problem I have is that the `ads.txt` tags need to be crawled by Google, which can take up to 24 hours on a new page/URL, time that I don't really have.

So I did the following. In my repo under `/public` folder I added a folder `/ad-test` with an `index.html` inside. When I serve it locally using `npm start` and go to `http://localhost:3000/ad-test`, it works fine.

Great, I thought and deployed it to the production environment, but now when I try to go to `http://[my-site]/ad-test` or `http://[my-site]/yo-test/index.html` it does not work (I get the React 404 site that I created).

I looked [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) and if I understand correctly, it is not possible to do it the way that I tried since the build stage will not include the public folder. Am I correct in this?

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I have a good knowledge of React and React Router in general, the app already uses `<Switch><Route ... /></Switch>` with a catch-all route directing to Not Found Component and the bottom.

The problem I have is that we include some ad scripts from an ad provider. The ads are not displayed in the application (adblockers totally removed from browser etc.) and the provider thinks that we have made errors in the React code.

We don't think that we made any errors (the ads were displayed fine in our test environment but not in prod) and we have to prove that React is not to blame for the ads not showing.

To do this we created a static HTML file with all ads hardcoded, no React components or other things that might disturb. BUT, because of ads and Google crawlers and ads.txt, we need to have the static test page under the same domain as our main page/application.

This is why I ask if it is possible to somehow add a static HTML that can be reached from `http://my.page/test-page.html` without being "intercepted" by react router, i.e. it exists outside React but on the same server.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use react by create-react-app, it means you are building a single-page application.

What this means is that after running `npm run build` you will have a **build** folder with only one html file called index.html in that fold.

This index.html does not know and has no relationship with your added '**index.html**' in **ad-test** folder.

If you want your ad-test html to be recognised by react, you need to make it a component of app.js and use react-router to give it a pathname.

It is very simple.

**First,** install react-router-dom;

**Second,** set up react-router-dom;refer to https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

**Third,** give your add-test component a pathname.Your js code should look something like this:

```
<Route path='/ad-test' component={AdTest} />
```

**IMPORTANT**:

After you deploy your app, always remember you just built a single-page application.

You only have **one html** in your app.

Please make sure when you test your app after you deployed you must tell your service provider that no matter what pathname a user inputs in the address bar you always redirect it to the index.html

**The build stage includes the public folder:**

If you have a picture in the public folder, and this picture was imported to other components it will be shown after you run **npm run build**

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already know that React is a SPA and how to use React Router, this is not the first React app that I've built. Sorry if that was not clear. My question was if I can get the router to somehow disregard a path during build so that I can use that path for another HTML page/file. But I guess that the answer is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with webserver configurations? It is usually setup to redirect all traffic to index.html. Maybe exclude your static html path from redirection?

- Place test-page.html in public folder like
  public/path-to-static-html/test-page.html
- Configure webserver for
  directing all traffic to index.html EXCEPT /path-to-static-html which
  will be directed to test-page.html.
  For example, in case of Apache
  you will be setting the DirectoryIndex directive.